# Fan speed monitor Software for Macbook Pro Unibody on Windows

Tags: windows-7, macbook, fan, temperature

I've tried multiple temperature monitor and fan speed software on my Macbook Pro Unibody under Windows 7 64-bit RC. None of them can report the fan speed. Currently I'm using SpeedFan which reports the CPU temperature of each of the two cores, but is not able to detect or interface with the Fans. 
Has anyone had any luck with this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php) `4.38` or higher?

> **`4.38`**
>    added full support for Windows 7 32 and 64 bit

Could not confirm MacBookPro support.

Comment: Yes. Using SpeedFan 4.38 already. No luck with that either. I believe its a chipset issue, but I might be wrong

Answer (score 1):

most likely the reason why none of them apps will give you any info is because most unibody MacBooks do not have fans, and if you are using one with a fan, its fan will only run if the component that it is supposed to be cooling reaches a certain temperature. simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

As nik pointed out, SpeedFan 4.38 is the best tool available to monitor temperature, but there is currently no tool available to monitor fan speed on the latest Macbook Pro Unibody machines in Windows

Answer (score 0):

Try [CPUID HWMonitor](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html), in my experience it has much better support for various sensors compared to SpeedFan.